# Rails - Table still in schema.rb after rails destroy scaffold and drop_table migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations, scaffolding, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to remove an old model etc., that I had created by scaffolding several migrations past. So I followed the advice in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15648268/what-is-the-best-way-to-drop-a-table-remove-a-model-in-rails-3) thread and ran a drop_table migration and the `rails d scaffold Modelname` command (maybe I did that first, not sure anymore).

As far as I can tell that removed the table and all the other files that had been created by the scaffolding, but my issue is that the schema.rb still includes the table! I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20464924/rails-migration-does-not-change-schema-rb) that I could probably fix this issue by running `rails db:drop db:create db:migrate`, but I was wondering **if there is a way to fix schema.rb without resetting the database completely?** (Unfortunately I started populating my db by console while I was adding parts to my app instead of writing a proper seed file.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can drop the table from rails console, for example the model is user then your table will be users

$rails console

Then just type:

```
ActiveRecord::Migration.drop_table(:users)
```

### Additional answer for user problem:

to update table schema in schema.rb you can use

$ **rake db:schema:dump**

Comment: I don't think the table exists anymore. I tried to look it up in the rails console and it gave me an error that said there was no table with the name of my previous model. (Which makes sense, since the drop_table migration had worked without throwing an error.) My problem is only that the **schema.rb** didn't update.

Comment: from rails console you can try rake db:schema:dump to dump table schema to schema.rb

Comment: Yes, that fixed it for me! Thank you @widjajayd! If you edit this into your original answer I will accept it :)